# Adding shared DTOs to the Client project and remove the Shared project in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In a webassembly asp.net core hosted project, I am asked to remove the shared project and add shared classes to a folder in the Client project, This works because the server project has a reference to client project. so everything works.

But my question is, will this cause problems in the future and in the production website?